# Capturing output of shell command in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a function that will accept a gem name and run Ctrl-P in the directory of that gem based on what Bundler shows. Right now I'm stuck on how to capture the output from the shell command.

So far I have:

```
function! GemCtrlP(gem_name)
   execute '!bundle list ' . a:gem_name
endfunction
```

I want to save the output of the of that `bundle` call and then pipe that into CtrlP. I can do the CtrlP part, but I'm not sure how to capture the shell output

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capturing arbitrary vim commands can be achieved by using the `:redir` command.
For shell commands, it is usually easier to use the `system()` function.

See the help at

```
:h :redir
:h system
```

There should be enough examples in the help (or look at some plugins).

Comment: It seems like system is actually showing a null character or something: `async_job-7ba2b1e64340^@`. Is there a way to strip that extra `^@` out? I'm looking at ag.vim for examples, but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Those are probably binary nulls. Recent Vims replace those by SOH (0x01). You should be able to strip those using substitute() function

Comment: Was able to just pipe it into tr

Comment: @576i indeed, but you not always want to have the output thrown into your actual document.

Answer (score 1):

More thorough version of what Christian posted:

```
function! GemCtrlP(gem_name)
  let path = system('bundle list ' . a:gem_name . ' | tr -d "\n"')
  execute 'CtrlP ' . path
endfunction
```